# R: Calling an object from R environment in a loop?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of objects in the R environment which I want to call them in a loop.

assume `x1, x2, x3, x4` are data frames in R environment, and `NAME_0` is a column in all of the dfs.

What I am aiming to do is:

```
for (i i 1:4) {
  print(unique(paste0('x',i)$NAME_0)
}
```

I get an error: `object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`

I am not sure how to circumvent this!?

Comment: Use `get()` to turn a string in the value of the variable of the same name. For example `print(unique(get(paste0('x',i))$NAME_0))`